# Pull data from different workbooks in excel

Tags: excel, vba, pull

I'm trying to pull data from workbooks with different names with the  InputRng in VBA, the code works perfectly in the same workbook but I need to get the data from other many workbooks that have different names always.  Below is my code.

```
Sub CopyData()

   Dim Rng As Range
   Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range
   xTitleId = "Administración de insumos"

   Set InputRng = Application.Selection
   Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Rango :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
       InputRng.Copy

   Workbooks("sh3").Activate
   Sheets("Hola").Select
   Application.Goto Reference:="R1C1"
   ActiveSheet.Paste

End SUb
```

How can I get the data from the other workbooks with that function or if exists another way to do it

Thanks a lot

This is the line with Application.GetOpenFilename

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim source As Worksheet

*ChDir "\\pr0980nas\bases 2010 2019"*
Set source = Workbooks("Libro4").Sheets(1)

fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Files (*.xlsb), *.xlsb")
   Set InputRng = Application.Selection
   Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Seleccionar Rango :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
       InputRng.Copy

   Workbooks("Libro4").Activate
   Sheets("Hola").Select
   Application.Goto Reference:="R1C1"
   ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: [`Application.GetOpenFilename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getopenfilename) to get a filename to open?

Comment: @BigBen The problem is that the files are in shared networks

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem for getting their filename as already noted, and then opening them.

Comment: @BigBen How could I modify the code for calling the data from the other workbook? Thanks

Comment: Taking a guess - here's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/office/vba/api/excel.application.getopenfilename) in Spanish, if that's helpful.

Comment: @BigBen Friend, it doesn't work, The InputRng stand in the workbook where the macro is

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with how you've tried to implement `Application.GetOpenFilename` or how you're opening/referencing those other workbooks?

Comment: @BigBen I can get data from other workbook with the variable source but the problem is if I do tha task with many workbooks

Comment: @BigBen The idea is to be able to get data from whatever workbook